# the text-box does't change the color in javascript

Tags: javascript

First, Happy New Year everyone!

I tried make a Form in which the Check Boxes(text)at the start(calling a function, `verif()`) where they must be in different color than as soon the user input a name the Colors must change in white, also I use the method, `setCustomValidity` to advice the user to fill the box in a case he(she) forgot but even I don't get the error massage where I must fill the box. 
Unfortunately my plan looks has error but I don't know where is that.

```
<section id="secty">
<h1 id="demo">Managing Form</h1>
<form id="usuer_register" name="usuer_register" method="post">

<table>
<tr><td>Name&#58;</td>
<td><input type="text" id="nam" name="nam"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last name&#58;</td>
<td><input type="text" id="name1" name="name1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Age&#58;</td>
<td><input type="text" id="age" name="age"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" id="regist" name="regist"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</section>
<script>
        function start(){
                    var x=document.getElementById("nam");
                    var y=document.getElementById("name1");
                    x.addEventListener("input", verif, false);
                    y.addEventListener("input", verif, false);
                    verif();    
             }
               function verif(){

               if(x.value=="" && y.value==""){
               x.setCustomValidity("Enter Name or Lastname");
               x.style.background="#803ADD";
               y.style.background="#803ADD";

                              }
             else{
                   x.setCustomValidity("");  // this restart as default;
                   x.style.background="#FFFFFF";
                   y.style.background="#FFFFFF";

                }
        }
        window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch here to re-work. Check the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript comments in the code below for details, but the main point is that HTML, CSS, and JavaScript already provide most of the functionality you are looking for. If you simply add `required` to the `input` elements that cannot be blank, you'll get automatic validity checking and styling.

Check our how [HTML5 Form Validity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form Validation</title>
  <style>
    /* CSS provides valid and invalid pseudo-classes which will automatically
       kick in based on the validity of form elements */
    .validate:valid { background-color:#fff; }
    .validate:invalid { background-color:#803ADD; }  
    
    label { display:inline-block; width: 5em; }
    form > div { margin-bottom: .2em; }
  
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <section>
    <h1>Managing Form</h1>
    <!-- Don't forget to fill in the action attribute of the form! -->
    <form id="usuer_register" name="usuer_register" method="post" action="">
    
      <!-- Do not use tables for layout! They are only for displaying tabular data. -->
      <div>
        <!-- Use label elements with form fields for better accessibility.
             Now, clicking on the label text focuses the field. Also, type="text"
             is not required on textboxes as "text" is the default type. 
             Lastly, just add the "required" attribute for automatic validity checking. -->
        <label for="fName">Name: </label><input id="fName" name="fName" class="validate" required>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="lName">Last Name: </label><input id="lName" name="lName" class="validate" required>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="age">Age: </label><input id="age" name="age">
      </div>
      <div>
        <!-- Submit Buttons shouldn't have a name because they 
             don't have any data that you would want submitted
             along with the form. -->
        <input type="submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </section>

  <!-- As long as your script element is the last element
       in the body, there is no need for a "start" function 
       or a "load" event hander. The following code will just
       run when it is reached and at this point in the document
       all the HTML has been parsed. -->
  <script>
    // Use meaningfull variable names
    let fName = document.getElementById("fName");
    let lName = document.getElementById("lName")
  
    // The inputs will be invalid initially, so flag them
    // that way from the start
    fName.setCustomValidity("Enter First Name");
    lName.setCustomValidity("Enter Last Name");  
  
    fName.addEventListener("input", verif);
    lName.addEventListener("input", verif);
  
    function verif(){
      // The field has recieved input, so the required validation
      // requirement has been met.
      this.setCustomValidity("");
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Happy New Year!